# Bottom navigation disappears when route clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a very basic app where I am trying to learn react-router and how I can use it for other apps. When I use the bottom navigation to navigate to a new route, my bottom navigation disappears.

I have tried putting my routes at the bottom of the App component but nothing seems to help. If I reload the /meals route manually the navigation re-appears.

Here is my root app component

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <NavBar sideBarOpen={false}/>

        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/meals" component={Meals} />
          </Switch>
        </main>

        <BottomNav />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here is my meals component

```js
class Meals extends React.Component{

    public render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div>Meals Component</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

On initial app load, I can see both navigation menus:

[See initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKEsf.jpg)

When I click on the meals nav link, my bottom nav is removed:

[Missing bottom nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6lg8.jpg)

Here is my bottom nav component. I am using the react-router redirect to change routes.

```js
class BottomNav extends React.Component<BottomNavProps,BottomNavState>{

    constructor(props: BottomNavProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            route : '/' 
        }     
        this.setRoute = this.setRoute.bind(this);
    }

    public setRoute = (route: string) => {
        this.setState({
            route: route
        })
    }

    public render() {

        if (this.state.route === "meals") {
            return <Redirect to='/meals' />
        }

        return (
            <div className="grow">
                <BottomNavigation className="bottomNavigation" value={this.state.route} onChange={(event, newValue:string) => { this.setRoute(newValue); }} showLabels>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" icon={<HomeIcon />} value=""/>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Lists" icon={<PlaylistAddCheckIcon />} value="lists" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Menus" icon={<MenuBookIcon />} value="menus" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Meals" icon={<RestaurantMenuIcon />} value="meals" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="more" icon={<MoreHorizIcon />} />
                </BottomNavigation>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to be able to maintain my top/bottom/drawer navigation while navigating through the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bottom nav component you have the `if` statement inside of your `render` function:

```
if (this.state.route === "meals") {
    return <Redirect to='/meals' />
}
```

This is basically saying that if the route is `meals` redirect to the `meals` route, which doesn't make any sense because the user is already there. When the condition is met, returning the `<Redirect to='/meals' />` component will cause the HTML that would render the navigation to not be reached.

This `if` statement is blocking the component from rendering when on the `meals` route, so it makes sense that it doesn't display when the route changes to that.

Remove the `if` statement in your `render` function and you should see the navigation rendering when your route changes to `/meals`.

**Bottom Nav Component:**

```
class BottomNav extends React.Component<BottomNavProps,BottomNavState>{

    constructor(props: BottomNavProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            route : '/' 
        }     
        this.setRoute = this.setRoute.bind(this);
    }

    public setRoute = (route: string) => {
        this.setState({
            route: route
        })
    }

    public render() {

        return (
            <div className="grow">
                <BottomNavigation className="bottomNavigation" value={this.state.route} onChange={(event, newValue:string) => { this.setRoute(newValue); }} showLabels>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" icon={<HomeIcon />} value=""/>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Lists" icon={<PlaylistAddCheckIcon />} value="lists" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Menus" icon={<MenuBookIcon />} value="menus" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Meals" icon={<RestaurantMenuIcon />} value="meals" />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="more" icon={<MoreHorizIcon />} />
                </BottomNavigation>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Making sense? Let me know if I can explain further!

**EDIT TO EXPLAIN QUESTION IN COMMENTS:**

https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/
If you're following Material UI's documentation (click the show source code button on the first example) you'll notice that the use of the `value` attribute on the `<BottomNavigation>` is intended to change the styling of the bottom nav to reflect the active route, but NOT to change the route itself.

In theory, it should work like this (I'm removing some of your type checking for clarity):

```
class BottomNav extends React.Component{

    constructor(props: BottomNavProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        }     
        this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
        this.handleRouteChange = this.handleRouteChange.bind(this);
    }

    // programmatically change the styling (material UI documentation)
    public handleValueChange = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            value
        })
    }

    // programmatically change the route
    public handleRouteChange = (newRoute) => {
      history.push(newRoute)
    }

    public render() {

        return (
            <div className="grow">
                <BottomNavigation className="bottomNavigation" value={this.state.value} onChange={(event, newValue) => { this.handleValueChange(newValue); }} showLabels>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" icon={<HomeIcon />} value="" onClick={() => {this.handleRouteChange('/')}} />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Lists" icon={<PlaylistAddCheckIcon />} value="lists" onClick={() => {this.handleRouteChange('/lists')}} />
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Menus" icon={<MenuBookIcon />} value="menus" onClick={() => {this.handleRouteChange('/menus')}}/>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="Meals" icon={<RestaurantMenuIcon />} value="meals" onClick={() => {this.handleRouteChange('/meals')}}/>
                    <BottomNavigationAction label="more" icon={<MoreHorizIcon />} onClick={() => {this.handleRouteChange('/more')}} />
                </BottomNavigation>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I was following [this tutorial](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/) to programmatically change routes. My bottom nav is using material UI so I am using the chosen value and trying to redirect the user. Without the redirect in the render method, how can I change the route?

Comment: @Kameron I've edited my response to explain your question - let me know if I can help further!

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for taking the time to provide a thorough response!